# ES5 Angular 2 Nested Component not quite working correctly

Tags: angular

I'm playing around with Angular 2 in ES5.  I realize ES5 isn't the latest and greatest, but due to project requirements and restrictions on what I can use, I have to use it.

I have created a component and tried to use another component inside of it as a directive.  Angular doesn't seem to recognize the nested component.  I see it in the rendered html source.  But nothing is rendered.  I feel like I'm missing a fundamental concept.

I've created a [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/R1i3c0s3ypNpjnhStDo0/) to play around with the code.

---

```js
(function() {


  var helloComponenet = ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'hello-comp',
      template: '<h2> Hello Component </h2>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });

  var myApp = ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<h1> Does Something </h1> <br>' + '<hello-comp></hello-comp>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {},
      directives: [helloComponenet]
    });


  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(myApp);
  });



}());
```

---

Comment: Take a look at this: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/06/even-better-es5-code-for-angular-2.html Especially the plunker. Seems to mimic your situation pretty exactly.

Comment: I had been looking at that one as well as a few others to do a stripped down hello world.  But I used the libraries from https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/ which were based on an example.  However, looking further into these,  they look to be a bit old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based the above example on https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2015/12/16/angular2-beta-javascript-component as well as a few other examples.  I didn't realize the above example was a year old.
Also in the code above,  the directives property should be in components instead of the class properties.